# Python and Boto3 object method NoRegionError()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have in my code that prints out the env variable value for AWS_REGION so that I can confirm this variable indeed exists, but I'm still getting a NoRegionError() from Boto3 object instance method. How can I confirm what Boto3 method is expecting in order for me to correct this error? Also, doesn't the 'client' object use the AWS_REGION env variable?

```
if choice == 'a'
            st_id = "xxxdhfda-sfffg"
            print("st id is:")
            print(st_id)
            print("region is:")
            print(os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
            #sfleet.cancel_sfleet_request(sfleet)
            # low level ec2 client
            client = boto3.client('ec2')
            client.cancel_spot_fleet_requests(
                SpotFleetRequestIds = [ st_id ],
                TerminateInstances=True
            )
        else:
            return False
```

output:

```
region is:
us-east-1
:
:
:

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
        raise NoRegionError()
    NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to be setting `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, not `AWS_REGION`. See the [documented list of env. variables](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) for boto3.